# objectmapper only serialize specific fields

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I want to write a function that only serializes a POJO with given implicit field names.

For example,

```
class Car{
    public int id;
    public String type;
    public Manufacture manufacture;
}

Class Manufacture{
   public int id;
   public String name;
}
```

if I want to serialize a Car object with a given list(i.e. [**Car.id**, **Car.Manufacture.name**])
Then I want to get

```
{
    Car:{
        id: xxx,
        Manufacture: {
            name: xxx
        }
    }
}
```

Another example, given list = [**Car.type**]
Then I should get

```
{
    Car:{
        type: xxx
    }
}
```

I am currently trying to override the **serializeAsField** method to check if the field is in the given list, but the problem here is that I don't know the depth, then I cannot correctly compare the current field with the list.

How could I achieve it? Are there any other ways?

Comment: What is your goal? Can you provide an example of what you get vs. what you expected? The question is not clear.

Comment: How do you currently serialize your data as JSON? Which API are you using? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code you have, if possible as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the unwanted fields with the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

On-the-fly filtering
Here is a Baeldung article that discusses using a filter to
determine which fields are serialized:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

I suspect that is the answer you want.

Comment: if the unwanted fields are implicit

Comment: There is no magic.  You must identify what you want and what you dont want.

Comment: The wanted fields are generated in runtime, I believe I should override some methods to achieve it.